# AMD GPU fan is making a lot of noise

Tags: amd-graphics, gpu, fancontrol

I'm coming from windows 10 and my AMD 6770 fan is incredibly loud. What is there I can do about it? According to my lm-sensors scan the card seems to be at only +50.0°C.